UDP multicast sometimes works sometimes does not in Windows 10
I have a very small network that is running IEEE 1588 PTP between the devices. The protocol is being communicated over UDP multicast on 224.0.1.129, and I have a PTP NIC on a Windows 10 machine that sometimes will be able to see these multicast messages, but sometimes it will not. If I restart the computer or restart the NIC sometimes that will help it to start seeing the messages.
To make things simpler I'll describe what I'm seeing when the system is working as expected, and when it's not working
When not working

Viewing NIC in wireshark with promiscuous mode off

Only PTP messages from the local NIC are visible


Viewing NIC in wireshark with promiscous mode on

All PTP messages from all devices are visible



When it's working

Viewing NIC in wireshark with promiscuous mode off or on

All PTP messages from all devices are visible



If I run the command netsh int ip show joins it shows that the NIC that I want to receive the multicast messages is joined to 224.0.1.129, and it shows this when the multicast messages are working and when they are not working.
Is there something else that I can do to more reliably make those multicast messages visible to that NIC, or is my best bet just to force the NIC into promiscuous mode and running it that way? I was really hoping I could avoid running in promiscuous mode because there is a lot of other traffic on the network that I wouldn't want it wasting time handling that is definitely not intended for that NIC.
